# Omitting "While + subject + verb to be"?

Tags: omissibility

" I hurt my knee playing soccer "
Is this sentence right? If yes, how come?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The sentence could be rewritten

> I, playing soccer, hurt my knee.

The participle *playing* is used as an adjective, modifying *I*.

It also could be read as

> I hurt my knee [while I was] playing soccer.

Both constructions work. Words are often implied [and omitted] in English.

Comment: So it is totally fine to omit "While". I mean I know it's valid to say " I hurt my knee while playing football ", but still valid with omitting "While"? And is it academically known? Thanks for your help BTW.

Comment: Yes it is. There is no ambiguity or oddness about your construction.

Comment: Note that what’s being left out is not necessarily _while_: it can also very commonly be _by_ (or _on_ or some other preposition). If you hurt your knee playing soccer, the meaning most commonly intended is that you hurt your knee _by_ playing soccer (playing soccer is the _reason_ that you hurt your knee). On the other hand, if you fell asleep playing soccer, there is no doubt that _while_ is what’s left out, and if you blew all your money playing soccer, _on_ is what’s left out. With _by/on/etc._, you cannot add “I was”, since they cannot take clauses as their objects.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet All excellent points. I think they deserve an answer.

Comment: It's a reduced adverbial clause, as John Lawler explains in his answer at the linked question. Not an adjectival. It modifies the verb, describing cause.

Comment: So this adverbial clause could be reduced in two way? [while I was] and [I was], is that right?

Comment: @Mazen Draou "I hurt my knee while/when I was playing soccer" may be shortened to "I hurt my knee while/when playing soccer" and further to "I hurt my knee playing soccer". But "I hurt my knee playing soccer", as Janus says, may be short for "I hurt my knee through playing soccer" etc. The more you omit, the more people have to guess at.